# QuickBooks - Cloud-Hosted Enterprise version - How to keep Web Connector running?

Tags: integration, desktop, quickbooks, enterprise, connector

I'm new to integrating with QuickBooks. Our client has a Cloud-hosted Enterprise version and wants us to integrate it to our web service. If I'm not mistaken, the QuickBooks API only works with QuickBooks Online, but not any of the Desktop versions.

Consequently, I would need to keep an instance of the QuickBooks Web Connector running so it would post data to our web service periodically. However, given the environment that the client is using is hosted on the cloud, I'm wondering if the Web Connecter will still run even when the client is no longer logged into the computer/cloud. If not, what are my options? And also, if I were to develop a custom connector (using the SDK) to do the same thing, where would this custom connect sit?

Thanks!

Ken

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if the Web Connecter will still run even when the client is no longer logged into the computer/cloud.

You need to ask your hosting provider about this. Some QuickBooks hosting providers will keep the login session open, others will auto-close it.

> If not, what are my options?

Are you sure you need to exchange data, even when no one is in QuickBooks to see the data was exchanged? It can't be queued and sit and wait until the Web Connector is open next?

> And also, if I were to develop a custom connector (using the SDK) to do the same thing, where would this custom connect sit?

It would sit alongside QuickBooks, on the hosted machine. Same situation.